# ADF V2 - Schedule Trigger

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can’t find what I’m missing … I’m actually trying to schedule a Pipeline in ADF V2 following the documentation here => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

The created scheduler is as follow …

[image]

And never start … any hint on  :

1.Where am I wrong?

2.Find why the trigger never start …

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you started the trigger? With PowerShell this is done by:
Start-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name ""

Comment: Actually ... no, i'm creating the trigger with C# and i didn't notice a start method, i will give it a second look.

Comment: There is a BeginStart method, just tried it and it worked !